# Find a $3\times 3$ matrix $X$, such that $X^{3}$ = specific matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Given a matrix $A$ find a matrix $C$ such that $C^3$=$A$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27753/given-a-matrix-a-find-a-matrix-c-such-that-c3-a)

I have stumbled upon the following question while studying for a test in linear algebra:

Find a matrix $X $ of $3  \times 3$ such that:

$X^3 = $
$
 \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0 & -1 & 1 \\
-1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \end{array} \right) $

I've never seen such questions before and I don't even know if I'm supposed to know how to solve it. Can anyone help me?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27753/given-a-matrix-a-find-a-matrix-c-such-that-c3-a

Comment: Hint: diagonalize.

Answer (score 0):

For this particular question, you only need to verify that $\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1 & 1 \\
-1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}^3=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1 & 1 \\
-1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$. In general, if you want to find a matrix $X$ such that $X^3=A$ for some given $A$, you may try to diagonalize $A$ as $PDP^{-1}$ for some diagonal matrix $D$ and some invertible matrix $P$, and then set $X=PD^{1/3}P^{-1}$, where $D^{1/3}$ is the entrywise cubic root or $D$. You may use a [computer algebra system](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%7B0,-1,1%7D,%7B-1,0,1%7D,%7B0,0,1%7D%7D) to help you.

Comment: You could explain the P=NP? problem using this answer.