# Given the matrix $A^3$, find A

Tags: linear-algebra

Given the matrix $A^3= \begin{bmatrix}83&84\\42&41\end{bmatrix}$, find A

I only know how to use the basic method to find A, which is $A^3= \begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}^3$, then solve a,b,c,d.
Is there any other method?

Comment: Not a hint, but another general method is to diagonalise, and then go from there

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27753/given-a-matrix-a-find-a-matrix-c-such-that-c3-a).

Comment: $A$ has nice entries, $1,2,3,4$, this exercise is well built.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $B:= A^3$ has minimal polynomial $(x-125)(x+1)$ so to apply the function $x \mapsto \sqrt[3]{x}$ we have to find a polynomial $p(x) = ax+b$ such that
$$p(125) = \sqrt[3]{125} = 5, \quad p(-1) = \sqrt[3]{-1} = -1.$$
We get that $p(x) = \frac1{21}(x-20)$ so
$$\sqrt[3]{B} = p(B) = \frac1{21}(B-20I) = \begin{bmatrix}3 & 4 \\ 2 & 1  \end{bmatrix}.$$
This is certainly a cube root of $B$.

Comment: I think that is not immediately obvious what you are doing with your $p(x)$. So I'll explain: $A^3=PD^3P^{-1}$ and $A=PDP^{-1}$ so $p(A^3)=Pp(D^3)P^{-1}=PDP^{-1}=A$ and since $D,D^3$ are diagonal with only $2$ values,we can go from one to another with an affine polynomial. We would need a quadratic for $3\times 3$ matrix, and so on...

Comment: I'm not the downvoter though...

Comment: @zwim I was going for the application of the holomorphic functional calculus on the function $z \mapsto z^{1/3}$ (principal cube root) which is holomorphic on a neighbourhood of $\{125,-1\}$. Then we can recall how is this defined on the Jordan form and realize that we only need a polynomial which coincides with the cube root on the spectrum.

Comment: Anyway, from this approach it is in no way clear that the cube root we got is actually equal to $A$ (which I never claimed), maybe that's what's bothering someone.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint :** $A^3$ is diagonalizable and its eigenvalues are $5^3$ and $(-1)^3$.

Answer (score 0):

Since the roots of the characteristic polynomial are $-1,125$, two distinct roots, in dimension two, $A^3$ is diagonalizable.  Find a basis of eigenvectors, $\{v_1,v_2\}$.  Then conjugate by the matrix $P$ whose columns are those eigenvectors, to get $A=P\begin{pmatrix}-1&0\\0&5\end{pmatrix}P^{-1}$.